# Google Drive.Permissions.update started to fail in "500 OK" exception

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I have used following kind of Java code (in AppEngine) to transfer ownership of a file in Google Drive. Suddenly this started to fail with server "500 OK" error. Has something changed or what could be the reason for this?

```
// first add new owner as "writer"
Permission newPermission= new Permission();
newPermission.setValue(newOwnerEmail);
newPermission.setType("user");
newPermission.setRole("writer");
Insert insert = service.permissions().insert(fileId, newPermission);
newPermission = insert.execute();

// then transfer ownsership
newPermission.setRole("owner");
newPermission.setValue(newOwnerEmail);
Update update = drive.permissions().update(fileId, newPermission.getId(), newPermission);
update.setTransferOwnership(true);
update.execute();
```

The exception message is simply like this, which does not tell much ...?

```
500 OK
{
  "code" : 500,
  "message" : null
}

at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1045)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution with these fixes:

1) Updated Drive API library to 1.17.0

2) When preparing the ownership transfer set the new owner permission role to "owner" immediately. In earlier API version it had to be "writer" first.

Here's the corrected code snippet:

```
// first add new permission as "owner"
Permission newPermission= new Permission();
newPermission.setValue(newOwnerEmail);
newPermission.setType("user");
newPermission.setRole("owner");
Insert insert = service.permissions().insert(fileId, newPermission);
newPermission = insert.execute();

// then transfer ownsership
newPermission.setValue(newOwnerEmail);
Update update = drive.permissions().update(fileId, newPermission.getId(), newPermission);
update.setTransferOwnership(true);
update.execute();
```